# Upgrading to Play 2.3.9 from Play 2.2.3 - Can not compile

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I have been struggling to get this resolved for past couple of days. My previous version of Play is 2.2.3 and I want to move to 2.3.9.

I made following changes  as per their document.
1) Changed project/build.properties file to sbt.version=0.13.5
2) Change the version of the Play plugin in project/plugins.sbt

'addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.9")'

I do not need sbt-web so I did not made those changes.

When I run command "activator" on my project I get following error

```
error: object Project is not a member of package play
play.Project.playJavaSettings
     ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I am new to this framework. Any suggestions on how to get this resolved? Do I need to make any other changes?

Comment: Could you paste your `build.sbt`

Answer (score 0):

In your build.sbt use this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

instead of:

```
play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

Comment: Thanks Vicky21. I made changes. It is still failing . Here is the error.      'C:\MyProject\modules\newmodule\build.sbt:1: error: object Project is not a member of package play
import play.Project._'

Comment: Can you please paste here where you are using in build.sbt:
import play.Project.
And for what you need it.
I have a java project running on activatorand I am not using play.Project package

Comment: Here is my build.sbt file. I have 2 build.sbt files. 1 at application level and another at sub project level. 
build.sbt at main application level :
'import play.PlayJava

name := "myapplication"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaCore
)     

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

lazy val anotherservice = project.in(file("modules/anotherservice"))
  .dependsOn(root).aggregate(root)

  
Keys.fork in Test := false'

Comment: Sorry the text is not getting formatted. Have to learn how to do that.

Comment: build.sbt at anotherservice level  
        import play.PlayJava    
    
    name := "anotherservice"
    version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    
    lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
    
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      javaJdbc,
      javaEbean,
      cache,
      javaCore
    )
    
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.7.5"
     )
     
    Keys.fork in Test := false

<code>

Comment: Your error message:  'C:\MyProject\modules\newmodule\build.sbt:1: error: object Project is not a member of package play import play.Project._' 

means that you are using import play.Project. In the build.sbt code you pasted this does not show. Please verify both of your build.sbt if there is any access to play.Project package and remove.

Comment: @trextrex Edit your question and paste your build.sbt in there so it's readable.